# How can I detect a "long touch" gesture with the Hololens 2? (Unity3D with MRTK)

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

In my Hololens 2 app I want to add a context menu to each hologram that the user can open by touching the hologram for 2 seconds. It should basically look like this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/mixed-reality/guides/media/touch-dwell-animation.gif

(Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/mixed-reality/guides/authoring-gestures-hl2)

But I cannot find any code examples for this. Do you have any ideas what I need to add for this or any piece of documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Interactable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/ux-building-blocks/interactable) component can meet your request, it will catch input actions and funnel these interactions into events to responsive. To make this possible, the Interactable component provides different types of out-of-box event receivers to respond to different types of input. Among them, [InteractableOnHoldReceiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.ui.interactableonholdreceiver?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.6.0) is used to trigger after pressing Interactable for a period. For how to add the event receiver into the Interactable please see [Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/ux-building-blocks/interactable#events)

Comment: Can you provide a code example on how to add this listener to an Interactable in a script? I am already using an Interactable, but I struggle to use the .AddReceiver<> Method correctly.

Comment: For how to add a new Event Receiver definition to Interactable component, please go through this section: [Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/ux-building-blocks/interactable#events)